# I want the dropdown toggle icon in sbadmin to show the alert("Hello World") when clicked.

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the dropdown icon on sbadmin2 to alert("Hello World").

This is part of my code for the page:

```
    <ul class='nav navbar-top-links navbar-right'>
    <li class='dropdown'>
    <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href = '#'>
    </ul>
    <i class='fa fa-print fa-fw'></i>  <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>
    </a>
```

this is the javascript

```
    function hello_world()
    {
        alert("Hello World");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change:

```
<i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>
```

to

```
<i class='fa fa-caret-down' onclick="hello_world();"></i>
```